# Next.js - React SSR Cannot find module './page.scss' when rendering on the server (client side rendered works fine after saving the file)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js

When you're using the `create-react-app` package you're able to have `.scss`-files compiled into `.css`-files as you type in them. You can then do `import './Header.css';` in your React component files and the styles are applied. It's easy to use your dev-tools and see where the styles are coming from.

Next.js tried to get everyone to use Styled-JSX to have your stylesheets inline inside your JSX files, similar to how web components (or Polymer) do it. I personally strongly dislike that approach.

Other problems:

- Styled-JSX isn't supported in my IDE (Webstorm) (even the work-around looks awful);
- Styled-JSX isn't supported in my dev-tools (Chrome) - there is no reference to what line the style is defined at;
- It makes my source code look like a garbled mess;
- How do I include 3rd party CSS solutions with Styled-JSX? Am I now supposed to add a `<link>` to my `<head>`? For everything external? How is that optimal usage of bandwidth? Referencing to files inside of `node_modules` feels awkward and bad, too.

So, just add rules to `next.config.js`, right?

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
        config.module.rules.push(
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        );
        return config
    }
};
```

And then just `import './Page.scss';` (Don't worry, it's valid CSS, not even SASS yet, I know I did not include the sass-loader here just yet. I try to keep it simple first.)

1. Refresh the page (Server Side Rendered): does NOT work;
2. Save the file (dynamically loaded after saving the file): it does work (until you reload the page);
3. Keeps complaining the [file can't be found](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cannot+find+module+scss+webpack), plenty of Google hits there, too. No real solutions that work today.

So, why doesn't it work with SSR?

Answer (score 0):

Note that [v5 of next.js will support CSS/Sass/Less *almost* out of the box](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/3578):

> For importing .css .scss or .less we’ve created modules which have sane defaults for server side rendering.

Until then, the following set of rules worked for me (assuming the `.sass` files are in `/styles` dir):

```
config.module.rules.push(
  {
    test: /\.(css|sass)/,
    loader: 'emit-file-loader',
    options: {
      // this path is relative to the .next directory
      name: 'dist/[path][name].[ext]'
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'raw-loader', 'postcss-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'raw-loader', 'postcss-loader',
      { loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          includePaths: ['styles', 'node_modules']
            .map((d) => path.join(__dirname, d))
            .map((g) => glob.sync(g))
            .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
        }
      }
    ]
  }
)
```